# Get referrer of Google Analytics current pageview

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics

in Google Analytics i have to set-up two Google Anlaytics instances (of two different Properties):

- the first one is instantiated as usual in whole website (ES: www.example.com/ )
- the second one in a folder of the main domain ( ES: www.example.com/blog/ )

What i have to do is rewriting the referrer of the second instance of Google Analytics reading it from the original referrer of the first instance of Google Analytics.

In this way i can get the original traffic source also in the report of the second property.

Rewriting the referrer of the second instance of Google Analytics is OK , but how can i get the original referrer of the first instance?

Is there some method similar to ga.getReferrer() or ga('get_referrer') ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the tracker has a [get method](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/accessing-trackers):

```
ga(function(tracker) {
  // Logs the URL of the referring site (if available).
  console.log(tracker.get('referrer'));
});
```

it would return the referrer of the current pageview on a landingpage, and "undefined" on a follow up page, not the referrer for the session on the original landingpage. Universal Analytics processes data on the server, so there is no way to get session based data on the client side. Your best chance would probably be to store document.referrer in a cookie and go with that.

(You are asking for the referrer of the current pageview, but since this would be simply document.referrer I do not think this is what you really want. Correct me if I am wrong).